# How to change AWS API Gateway method integration type to HTTP_PROXY with CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, openapi

In my case, AWS API Gateway should proxy every request and response through as they are. The API was created by importing an OpenAPI definition. I know how to manually set the method integration in the AWS console to HTTP proxy and set the endpoint URI.

I want to get rid of manual work and create a PowerShell script that loops through every method and sets those settings. But I haven't found the right command to update the integration type and URI.

After reading AWS CLI reference I have tried this command:

```
update-integration --rest-api-id  x0cm5muxxx --resource-id xvxxxx --http-method GET --integration-type HTTP_PROXY --profile user2
```

But it gives an error:

> "Unknown options: --integration-type, HTTP_PROXY"

Another CLI command I have tried without success is `update-method` with `--patch-operations`.

After the changes, the method's integration should look like this example:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> aws apigateway get-integration --rest-api-id  x0cm5muxxx --resource-id x1lxxx --http-method GET --profile user2
{
    "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "uri": "https://${stageVariables.Url}/api/v1/Productlist/CanOrder/{fnprodId}",
    "connectionType": "INTERNET",
    "requestParameters": {
        "integration.request.path.fnprodId": "method.request.path.fnprodId"
    },
    "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
    "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
    "cacheNamespace": "01lxxx",
    "cacheKeyParameters": [],
    "integrationResponses": {
        "200": {
            "statusCode": "200"
        }
    }
}
```

The next problem will be how to loop through every single method in the API for this update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help and correct command to change methods integration type is:

```
aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id $RestAPIid --resource-id $ResourceId --http-method GET --type HTTP_PROXY --integration-http-method GET --profile $Profile  --uri $uri
```

Edit: It have to be considered that put-integration command will lose all previous integration parameters. So after adding HTTP_PROXY integration I loop through all parameters and write them back.

If someone is trying to loop Rest API resources with Powershell  it goes like this simplified..

```
$array = Aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id  $RestAPIid --profile $MyProfile --query  [items[*].id]
$array | sort
"Resources:"
$array
""
"Amount of resources:"
echo $array.Length
""
 foreach ($arrayItem in $array) {
   "$arrayItem = " + $arrayItem.length
}
```

Comment: After further examination put-integration command loses original requestParameters so it broked something new.. Now we can get backend responses through API Gateway as  they are, but API Gateway doesn't pass request parameters to backend because put-integration dropped  them in process to change integration type.